# use 'this' keyword along with css pseudo selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to use pseudo selectors along with this attribute.
How can I use it.

```
$('input:valid').length
```

It will return 1 if its valid else 0 for invalid.

the same if I want to achieve using this how can I do that.
something like this.

```
$('input').focusout(function(){
var flag=$('this:valid').length;
console.log(flag);
})
```

But its not working. Please guide me how to do this.

Comment: You'll have to write a wrapper or extend a Jquery function..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
var flag = $(this).is(':valid'); //returns boolean
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
var flag=$(this).filter(':valid').length
```

REF: [**.filter() | jQuery API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)